# Yii CUserIdentity vs a User Model

Tags: php, oop, yii, yii-components, yii-inheritance

I have at least one model in my Yii project that will need to reference a particular user ID. In my SQL for the model I have something like `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id)`. I was going to go ahead and create a User model when I came across the docs for CUserIdentity. I have to admit I am confused. Is a CUserIdentity a user or a state associated with a particular user-case? I would like to use as much of the built-in Yii features as possible since they handle a lot of security-related issues from what I understand, and I am aware of the existence of some modules like `srbac` that handle user authentication and registration management. Please guide me in the right direction. (Also at issue: what is the relationship between models and components?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, do go ahead and create a `User` model, you will need it.

With that out of the way: `CUserIdentity` represents the concept of "who the user is", while  the `User` model represents "information about a user of my application". `CUserIdentity` is applicable in all cases where there is more than one kind of user (i.e. guest), while the `User` model is only applicable when you are storing information about the users yourself. Admittedly, in most cases *both* will be applicable and this is what creates the confusion.

Usually, the relation between the two is that `CUserIdentity`, in order to answer questions such as "who the user is", "is the user allowed to access this resource" etc. queries the `User` model from the database to get the information it needs to answer these questions. This relationship between the two concepts is also [documented](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#defining-identity-class) in the definitive guide to Yii. After e.g. authenticating the user, it would expose some or all of the information on the `User` model through its own properties (which you would have to define).

To give an example of a scenario where there would be no `User` model, think about a website that lets you log in using your LDAP user account. When the `CUserIdentity::authenticate` method is called, the component would authenticate the credentials against the LDAP server and after a successful authentication would again grab any other relevant information and expose it through its own properties.

Comment: Its been a long time from this question, but where do you put your OwnUserIdentity class and related model? Thanks!

Comment: @Jorge: A good default is for `OwnUserIdentity` to go into `protected/components/` and `User` into `protected/models/`.