# set the username and id according to facebook's username and id

Tags: facebook, yii

I ve been developing a facebook application on Yii and after the authentication i want to set the username and id according to the facebook username and id. As i am new to Yii I dont't have much idea about how to do it. Though when i tried to set the user id in my UserIdentity class, it gave an error saying that

```
Property "UserIdentity.id" is read only.
```

is there any other way to do it?

Comment: maybe have a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/facebook-connect/

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458940/yii-cuseridentity-vs-a-user-model/7459025#7459025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using for authentication now? If you set up a webapp you should have a UserIdentity class in components that extends CUserIdentity. This is usually where you would use setState(), like `$this->setState('first_name', $record->first_name);` to set the user's first name from a db record after authentication, as an example, which you can retrieve via `Yii::app()->user->first_name`

However, I think what you may be looking for is `Yii::app()->user->name = 'newname';` which changes the CWebUser property that CUserIdentity sets during authentication with the CUserIdentity::username value.

Either option is fine -- setting a custom Yii::app()->user->value or resetting the Yii::app()->user->name value, whichever works best for your app. (I wouldn't reset the user->id value tho.)

Answer (score 1):

Well that post by DroidUser really helped to get a better understanding of CUserIdentity class. Though when I opened the CUserIdentity.php in Yiiroot/framework/ i found that only getter methods for reading id and username has been defined there but not to set them.

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->username;
}
public function getName()
{
    return $this->username;
}
```

and that both of them return the username you logged in with, though i found a [CWebUser](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser) class which is also extended by IUserIdentity.
Here you can use

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('name',$value)
```

to actually set a field and assign some value to it and a similar getState method to read it.
I think this will solve my problem as all i want to do is to store some user identification values in a system-wide accessible variable.
Any suggestions?